# Multiple Azure CDN endpoints

Tags: azure, cdn, endpoint

We have a Azure CDN endpoint and a custom domain mapped to it cdn.ourcompany.com, so I can use two domains to access the CDN, my custom domain and azure CDN host (.vo.msecnd.net)

It is not possible to add another custom CDN domain to the endpoint in the Azure Management Portal, but I wonder if there is any work around I can do, perhaps doing something in my DNS?

Comment: What's the purpose of the 3rd domain host? Why can't you just use the other 2 options?

Comment: Need to serve 12 requests simultaneously to the client, most browsers has 5 connections limit per host

Comment: Can you merge the 12 requests into single requests by merging resource contents? Are these images, javascript, css - what is the resource type?

Comment: They are Json objects, it is a traffic management system that needs realtime information from multiple sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out there is no workaround I can do, but I am talking to a guy at Microsoft that says he can do it for me using a manual process, I didn't get an official position if this will be possible in the future, hope it will.

Comment: Confirmed - they were able to accommodate me as well. Another alternative: redirect other subdomains (ie media-cache1..7) to the az*.vo.msecnd.net domain but this carries different overhead. This feature is crucial for media intensive sites and would put Azure CDN on par with CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating another CNAME that maps to the CDN Host `.vo.msecnd.net` or your custom domain and it may work the same. I would `tracert` to verify.

Comment: I tried this approach but the CDN returns bad request (400) for hosts that are not configured in the portal

Comment: It looks like it must be limiting you to a single custom domain - possibly by checking the referrer.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know, currently you can only add a single custom domain to a CDN endpoint. i am not sure there's other workaround. You can submit a feature request on http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting. Most browsers allow 6 (not 5) simultaneous connections to a single domain. This is usually enough. If you have a 7th request, it will still work, but the request is only sent to the service when one of the former 6 requests return. If that’s not acceptable, you can either do as SilverNinja suggested: Combine multiple requests in a single request. Or you can use multiple storage accounts, which allow you to create one custom domain per account.

Answer (score 1):

Until last year you had to open a ticket with Microsoft, who would manually add an internal rewrite rule for each extra domain.

It has recently become possible to add multiple domains directly from the Windows Azure Management Portal. Select CDN, then click the CDN name, then Click Manage Domains from the controls at the bottom. This will open the "Manage custom domains" dialog, from where you can add and remove domain names (except for the one on top, which is the default CDN endpoint name).

You still need to verify each added domain with a CNAME record in your DNS.

Works fine here with six domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create multiple custom domains on Azure portal, just click on manage domains button on the bottom of the portal. I have multiple custom domain names here. What you need to do is to point your custom domain to CDN endpoint first and then add custom domains in the "Manage custom domains" page

[image]

[image]